# grep count multiple occurrences

Tags: bash, grep

Is it possible to do a grep count of multiple occurrences in a file in one single command? For example:

```
$ cat > file
blah alfa
beta blah
blah blahgamma
gamma
```

I can do:

```
grep -c 'alfa' file 
1 
grep -c 'beta' file  
1
grep -c 'gamma' file  
2
```

But is it possible to so domething like:

```
grep -c -e 'alfa' -e 'beta' -e 'gamma' -somemoreblackmagic file
```

and get the counts for each of them?

```
alfa 1
beta 1
gamma 2
```

Comment: Couldn't you `sort file | uniq -c` and then `grep` on that?

Comment: @slhck, please post that as an answer

Comment: @glenn Well, it doesn't follow the same output format, giving the count first, and then the keyword. If the OP thinks this is a solution, I'll be happy to provide a more detailed answer, of course :)

Comment: @slhck just pipe an awk print $2 $1 on there

Comment: This answer assumes that the search strings will be complete lines (i.e., the only thing on any line where they occur).  If the input is `alfax`, `alfay`, `alfaz` (on separate lines), this script will report `1 alfax` / `1 alfay` / `1 alfaz` rather than `3 alfa`.  An input line of `alfa beta` (on the same line) will result in a report of `1 alfa beta` rather than `1 alfa` / `1 beta`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think grep is capable of what you want to do.

Just use awk instead:-)

This solution may not work well for large files (is not optimized). And works for plain words only - not regexps. But it's easy to add some features if so desired.

Low end version with restrictions outlined in comments below:

```
awk '
{
    split($0, b); for (i in b) ++A[b[i]]
}
END {
    split("'"$*"'", a)
    for (i in a) print sprintf("%s %d", a[i], A[a[i]])
}
'
```

just give the search strings directly to the script

[EDIT]
fixed version with regex support (see comment below).
Please tell me if there still are any open issues.

```
# ---- my favorite ----
awk -F' ?-c ' '
BEGIN { split("'"$*"'", a) }
{ for (i = 2; a[i]; ++i) if (match($0, a[i])) ++A[i] }
END { for (i = 2; a[i]; ++i) if (A[i]) print a[i] " " A[i] }
'
# ---- my favorite ----
```

sample usage:

```
script_name -c alfa -c beta -c gamma << !
alfa
beta
gamma
gamma
!
```

gives:

```
alfa 1
beta 1
gamma 2
```

regex usage:

```
script_name -c   "^al"    -c "beta" -c gamma -c "m.$" << !
alfa
beta
gamma
gamma
!
```

gives:

```
^al 1
beta 1
gamma 2
m.$ 2
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: (1) Big problem: this solution assumes that the search strings will be separate words.  An input line of `alfalfa` would not count as an `alfa`.  (2) Interesting feature: this solution counts every occurrence on every line.  An input line of `alfa alfa alfa` would count as three occurrences of `alfa`.  This might be desirable, but it’s not consistent with `grep –c`, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: you are certainly right. I just added another solution that allows to specify an regexp as in egrep  counting occurencies in lines as grep does. I hope it's more compatible now:-)

Comment: argument quoting still may have issues though

Comment: @sparkie, thanks, the non-regexp version takes about a 80-100 seconds on my average sized files, which is pretty decent.

Answer (score 7):

You can get what you need just by using **grep**, **sort** and **uniq**.

```
grep -EIho 'alfa|beta|gamma' *|sort|uniq -c
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill Explanation is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28145101/619961

Comment: ahh, this has unnecessary extra flags, and removal reduces to my answer
I is just ignore binary, h is hide names of results, E is extended grep to parse the '|'. OP isnt grepping *, so no need for -EIh, just use -o in OP's case

Answer (score 4):

Another `awk` solution, with shell script wrapper thrown in:

```
#!/bin/sh –
awk '
BEGIN { split("alfa beta gamma", keyword)
        for (i in keyword) count[keyword[i]]=0
}
/alfa/  { count["alfa"]++ }
/beta/  { count["beta"]++ }
/gamma/ { count["gamma"]++ }
END   {
        for (i in keyword) print keyword[i], count[keyword[i]]
}'
```

If you want to be able to choose the search keywords at runtime (and provide them as arguments, as in sparkie’s answer), this script can be adapted to build the `awk` script dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for scriptability, reusability, and readability!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `-o` to collect occurrences, then count the number of occurrences with `wc -l`.

Works single:

```
grep -o 'alfa' file | wc -l
 1
grep -o 'beta' file | wc -l
 1
grep -o 'gamma' file | wc -l
 2
```

Group counts:

```
grep -o -e 'alfa' -e 'beta' -e 'gamma' file | wc -l
  4
```

Individual counts: (sorted by frequency)

```
grep -o -e 'alfa' -e 'beta' -e 'gamma' file | sort | uniq -c | sort
  1 alfa
  1 beta
  2 gamma
```

*Far more straight forward (and memorable) than other answers*

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'chomp;$s{$_}++ if /alpha|beta|gamma/ }{ print "$_ $s{$_}" for keys %s' file
```

Comment: This doesn't return the same result as `grep -c` if there is more than one word on each line.

Answer (score 0):

No grep cannot do this in one pass, I would suggest using awk:

```
awk -v pat='alfa beta gamma' '
  BEGIN { split(pat, p) } 

  { for(k in p) if($0 ~ p[k]) c[k]++ }

  END { for(k in p) print p[k], c[k]?c[k]:0 }
'
```

Or as a rather long one-liner:

```
awk -v pat='alfa beta gamma' 'BEGIN { split(pat, p) } { for(k in p) if($0 ~ p[k]) c[k]++ } END { for(k in p) print p[k], c[k]?c[k]:0 }'
```

*Explanation*

`pat` is split into the `p` array, which is then used to search for matches on each line (`$0 ~ p[k]`). The counters are held in the `c` array. The `c[k]?c[k]:0` bit uses the ternary operator to print 0 when `c[k]` is zero.

Note if your pattern contains space, you need to use a different delimiter between the patterns in `pat` and to update the `split` command accordingly.

*Testing*

Input:

```
cat << EOF > file
alfa
beta
gamma
gamma
EOF
```

Output with `pat='alfa beta gamma'`:

```
alfa 1
beta 1
gamma 2
```

Input:

```
cat << EOF > file
alfa beta
beta
gamma gamma
gamma alfa
alfalfa
alfa alfa
EOF
```

Output with `pat='^a a$ alfa beta gamma'`:

```
beta 2                                          
gamma 2
^a 3
a$ 6
alfa 4
```

The output matches in both cases the output from running `grep -c` with each pattern individually.

Comment: (1) A minor point: unlike `grep –c`, this will not report `0` occurrences of any string that appears 0 times in the input.  (2) Big problem: this solution assumes that the search strings will be the first word on a line.  An input line of `foo alfa` would not count as an `alfa`.  (3) Yet another problem: this solution assumes that the search strings will be separate words.  If the input is `alfax`, `alfay`, `alfaz` (on separate lines), this script will report `alfax 1` / `alfay 1` / `alfaz 1` rather than `alfa 3`.

Comment: @Scott: you're right, this doesn't work like `grep -c`. I'll have another stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `uniq` (with `sort`).

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
1 alfa
1 beta
2 gamma
```

You need `sort` if the file might not be sorted (in fact, only if the multiple occurences might not be on consecutive lines).

**UPDATE:**

Assuming that you have predefined patterns and they don't contain space:

```
$ PATTERNS='alfa beta gamma'

$ for P in $PATTERNS; do echo $P `grep -c $P file`; done
alfa 1
beta 1
gamma 2
```

Comment: Thanks I thought of this but the words to grep are not always at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Okay but now you changed your question to something different. You now imply that there is an explicit list given. I updated my answer as well then, see above.

Answer (score 0):

Here one sample from my daily work:

All Files ending FlowBase.java, Count occurence of String "Input*" > 1

Example: file will listed

"inputABD"

"inputABD"

$ for i in $(find . | grep FlowBase.java); do echo $i $(egrep "input.*" $i | sed 's/^.*"input//' | sed 's/";.*//' | uniq -c | awk '($1 > 1) { print $2}' | wc -l); done | awk '($2 > 0) {print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'sting1.*sting2' file | wc -l
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).